# How to take Azure Cosmos db local backup

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, backup

As a best practice after an environment is de allocated, we delete all the resources from the cloud, but we need the data stored in the cloud and also we are not able find any solution to take the Azure Cosmos DB backup locally

Answer (score 0):

I can only confirm that this is currently not possible.
Most of cloud providers don't offer such option for SaaS databases or even PaaS. In my opinion, the only solution is to use services such as Data Factory or Databricks, and dump your data to a storage.

[Copy and transform data in Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=data-factory)

The key question is whether such a backup will be valuable to you. I mean process performance and the data consistency.